# Message Broker (ODBC error on windows 7 running IBM Integration Bus V9.0.0.2)

Tags: oracle, odbc, messagebroker

I am using IIB v9.0.0 on Windows, using Oracle database as source application. While running the interface, I'm getting following below issue, when execute prepared SQL query:

```
SELECT HDR.SHIPMENT, HDR.EST_ARR_DATE, HDR.TO_LOC, HDR.TO_LOC_TYPE, 
 HDR.SHIP_DATE, HDR.FROM_LOC, HDR.FROM_LOC_TYPE, HDR.COURIER, 
 HDR.EXT_REF_NO_OUT, HDR.FR_INSPC_FLG, HDR.FR_TRNSMT_NUM, 
 HDR.FR_CRRR_SUB_NUM, DTL.SEQ_NO, DTL.ITEM, DTL.QTY_EXPECTED, DTL.DISTRO_NO ,DTL.TSF_TYPE  
FROM XXIF_ARV_SCH_HDR_IIB_S  HDR , XXIF_ARV_SCH_DTL_IIB_S  DTL  
 WHERE HDR.FR_BIH_STATUS = ? AND DTL.FR_BIH_STATUS = ? AND DTL.SHIPMENT = 
 HDR.SHIPMENT AND HDR.TO_LOC = ?
```

I have configured ODBC connectivity and run the command to save credentials
`mqsisetdbparms DevNode -n odbc::DSN_ORACLE -u XXIF_IIB -p XXIF_IIB`

ExceptionList:

```
RecoverableException
  File:CHARACTER:F:\build\slot1\S900_P\src\DataFlowEngine\ImbRdl\ImbRdlStatementGroup.cpp
  Line:INTEGER:650
  Function:CHARACTER:SqlStatementGroup::execute
  Type:CHARACTER:ImbESQLManager
  Name:CHARACTER:ImbESQLManager
  Label:CHARACTER:ImbESQLManager
  Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
  Severity:INTEGER:3
  Number:INTEGER:2488
  Text:CHARACTER:Error detected, rethrowing
  Insert
       Type:INTEGER:5
       Text:CHARACTER:XXIF_DBService.XXIF_ARV_SCH_DTL_IIB_S_OPS_GROUP.retrieveXxifASNDetails
  Insert
       Type:INTEGER:5
       Text:CHARACTER:3.2
  Insert
       Type:INTEGER:5
       Text:CHARACTER:SET dbResultSetRef.row[ ] = SPECIFICPASSTHRU('SELECT HDR.SHIPMENT, HDR.EST_ARR_DATE, HDR.TO_LOC, HDR.TO_LOC_TYPE, HDR.SHIP_DATE, HDR.FROM_LOC, HDR.FROM_LOC_TYPE, HDR.COURIER, HDR.EXT_REF_NO_OUT, HDR.FR_INSPC_FLG, HDR.FR_TRNSMT_NUM, HDR.FR_CRRR_SUB_NUM, DTL.SEQ_NO, DTL.ITEM, DTL.QTY_EXPECTED, DTL.DISTRO_NO , DTL.TSF_TYPE  FROM XXIF_ARV_SCH_HDR_IIB_S  HDR , XXIF_ARV_SCH_DTL_IIB_S  DTL  WHERE HDR.FR_BIH_STATUS = ? AND DTL.FR_BIH_STATUS = ? AND DTL.SHIPMENT = HDR.SHIPMENT AND HDR.TO_LOC = ?', Database.DSN_ORACLE, fr_bih_status, fr_bih_status, toloc);
  DatabaseException
       File:CHARACTER:F:\build\slot1\S900_P\src\DataFlowEngine\MessageServices\ImbOdbc.cpp
       Line:INTEGER:3246
       Function:CHARACTER:ImbOdbcStatement::checkRcInner
       Type:CHARACTER:
       Name:CHARACTER:
       Label:CHARACTER:
       Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
       Severity:INTEGER:3
       Number:INTEGER:2321
       Text:CHARACTER:Root SQL exception
       Insert
           Type:INTEGER:2
           Text:CHARACTER:-1
       Insert
           Type:INTEGER:14
           Text:CHARACTER:odbc32.dll
       DatabaseException
           File:CHARACTER:F:\build\slot1\S900_P\src\DataFlowEngine\MessageServices\ImbOdbc.cpp
           Line:INTEGER:3424
           Function:CHARACTER:ImbOdbcStatement::checkRcInner
           Type:CHARACTER:
           Name:CHARACTER:
           Label:CHARACTER:
           Catalog:CHARACTER:BIPmsgs
           Severity:INTEGER:3
           Number:INTEGER:2322
           Text:CHARACTER:Child SQL exception
           Insert
               Type:INTEGER:5
               Text:CHARACTER:IM001
           Insert
               Type:INTEGER:2
               Text:CHARACTER:0
           Insert
               Type:INTEGER:5
               Text:CHARACTER:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function
```

Anyone knows the issue, please check.

Comment: What database are you using? Your data source name suggests Oracle, but you are using the MSSQL ODBC driver.

Comment: And to check the database connectivity try running the command: mqsicvp DevNode -n DSN_ORACLE

Comment: Could you show your ODBC connection settings?

Answer (score 0):

Check the options that can be configured in ODBC connection, usually you must enable some options to run the sentences and the execution of procedures and functions properly.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows you need to enable checkbox "Enable Nchar support" on your user DSN.